# C++ how to implement templated converting binary operator overloads

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading

I'm trying to do this:

```
template<class Float>
struct Number {
  Float v;
  Number(Float iv = 0) : v(iv) {}
};

template<class F>
Number<F> operator+(Number<F> const& a, Number<F> const& b) {   
  return {a.v + b.v};
}

int main() {
  Number<float> y = Number<float>(1) + 2.0f;
  std::cout << y.v << "\n";
}
```

But it doesn't work.

```
main.cpp:15:38: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Number<float>' and
      'float')
  Number<float> y = Number<float>(1) + 2.0f;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~
main.cpp:10:11: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'Number<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'float'
Number<F> operator+(Number<F> const& a, Number<F> const& b) {   
          ^
```

And for some reason, this does work:

```
struct Number {
  float v;
  Number(float iv = 0) : v(iv) {}
};

Number operator+(Number const& a, Number const& b) { 
  return {a.v + b.v};
}

int main() {
  Number x = Number(1) + 2.0f;
  std::cout << x.v << "\n";
}
```

But I want the template case to work. Basically I'm looking for any kind of workaround to enable me to implement binary operators for Number that will allow one of the args to be something convertible to Number. Preferably c++14 compliant.

Edit: based on Richard's link below, I came up with this which seems to handle the multiple conversions case but still unfortunately requires 3 overloads of each operator:

```
template<class T>
struct identity {
  using type = T;
};

template<class T>
using convertible = typename identity<T>::type;

template<class Float>
struct Param {
  Float v;
};

template<class Float>
struct Number {
  Float v;
  Number(Float iv = 0) : v(iv) {}
  Number(Param<Float> iv) : v(iv.v) {}
};

template<class F>
Number<F> operator+(Number<F> const& a, Number<F> const& b) {
  return {a.v + b.v};
}
template<class F>
Number<F> operator+(Number<F> const& a, convertible<Number<F>> const& b) {
  return {a.v + b.v};
}
template<class F>
Number<F> operator+(convertible<Number<F>> const& a, Number<F> const& b) {
  return {a.v + b.v};
}

int main() {
  std::cout << (Number<float>{1} + 2).v << "\n";
  std::cout << (Number<float>{1} + Param<float>{2}).v << "\n";
  std::cout << (Param<float>{1} + Number<float>{2}).v << "\n";
  std::cout << (Number<float>{1} + Number<float>{2}).v << "\n";
  std::cout << (1 + Number<float>{2}).v << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Case (2): Non-templated functions will try a conversion to match argument types and `Number` has a converting constructor from `float`.  Case (1) templated functions will not try conversions - in more complex cases what type should the parameter(s) be when multiple possible conversions are available.  In addition for case (2) try making the constructor `explicit`

Comment: @RichardCritten Yeah I guess the standard makes sense in general. But usually c++ limitations have workarounds, so I'm hoping someone can help that way. In this specific case, the right conversion is always dictated by one of the args to binary op being exactly a Number<T>.

Comment: Example here (does not need C++ 20 - see answer below - but you will have to create some helper templates) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts  Specifically definition of `good(x, 1.2)`

Comment: This seems to lead to other problems down the road... I'm also trying make a vector add, which determines element type of result vector by decltype(Vec1()[0] + Vec2()[0]) but that operator+ doesn't search for converting overloads and substitution fails.

Answer (score 2):

Implicit conversions won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions).

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

So the deduction for template parameter `F` failed on the 2nd function parameter `b` in `Number(1) + 2.0f`, the implicit conversion from `float` to `Number<float>` won't be considered.

You can add another two overloads as

```
template<class F, class V>
Number<F> operator+(Number<F> const& a, V const& b) {   
  return {a.v + Number{b}.v};
}

template<class F, class V>
Number<F> operator+(V const& a, Number<F> const& b) {   
  return {Number{a}.v + b.v};
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZCEKTPS3wUBU7L2A)

Comment: If I want to support a 2nd type X where Number(X &) is defined, do I then have to write 4 versions of the + operator? Or is there a more elegant way to recognize the 2nd parameter is convertible to Number, but without becoming ambiguous for Number+Number